# Geocoding From Google Sheets Data

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I have a Google Form where I'm taking inputs from my high school classmates & teachers to buildup a google map where I'll make a "Network Map"(as I call it). I've 2 columns in the connected Spreadsheet named as **"District"** and **"Thana"** (in Bangladeshi format).

I need to merge those 2 columns into a new one named **"Full Adress"**, then I need to Geocode this column to get an approximately correct location of my schoolmates or teachers. Also, I need to share the created map with the respondents of my "Google Forms" so that they can see that map easily from their "Google Map" app in any kinds of device.

I don't know how to geocode or I don't have any idea about it.

Can I get some important resources/platforms to do this task efficiently without paying anything?
(Special note: I have to handle about **2k+ data** in that Sheet.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @My Routes' answer and to set the correct expectation, the **[Maps for Sheets](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/maps_for_sheets/268502135031)** should accomplish your Geocoding problems (as mentioned by @My Routes). But please keep in mind that you should use an **API key that associated in to a project that has an active billing account**. This is not a free service but once you enable billing, you are given free $200 monthly credits.

To learn more about the product's pricing, please check out **[Google Maps Platform APIs pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing)**.